# How to run multiple SQL scripts using a batch file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sql-scripts

I have a case where i have got 10+ `SQL script`.

I don't want to go and run all my scripts 1 by 1.

Is there a way that i can run all my scripts in succession in `SQL Management studio`.

I found [this](http://dotnetanalysis.blogspot.com/2011/04/run-multiple-sql-scripts.html) post. Creating a batch file seems easier.

This is all you need:

```
@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt


for %%f in (*.sql) do (
 (
sqlcmd.exe  -S servername -E   -d databasename -i %%f >>output.txt
)


pause
```

Replacing servername and databasename, but it seems to be not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: What appears in output.txt when you run the batch file?

Comment: @MarkBannister Willem started the batch process at 10:50:30.46. Then nothing else happens

Comment: What output do you get if you remove the `@echo off` command from the batch file and try again? Also, try adding `ECHO %PATH%` to the start of the batch file and check that the path for SQLCMD.EXE is included.

Comment: @MarkBannister Willem started the batch process at 11:18:51.16.

Comment: How about the path - did it include the path for SQLCMD.EXE? Additionally, what happens if you try running the batch command interactively, in a command prompt?

Comment: Also, have you tried removing the brackets and including the `sqlcmd.exe` on the same line as the `do`? I notice that you appear to have an unclosed parenthesis in your script.

Comment: @MarkBannister I just double clicked the batch file. It created the output file and then nothing happened... So it seems to not pickup the files in the folder.

Comment: You probably already know this, in case you don't, the script you posted will only run on machines that have SQL server installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Strored Procedure to call all your Scripts. You could also create a schedule plan to run the scripts automaticaly.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Do you got an error message from the script? Have you checked the path for '*.sql', which represents the sql scripts you want to run.

Comment: Only a thought: Try to delete the blanks between the option and the parameter

Comment: Still nothing. It just seems to skip all the files... Is the syntax even right?

Comment: The syntax seems to be allright, try the following 

ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt

for %%f in (*.sql) do (
(
 ECHO %%f >>output.txt
)

Run this script and see, if all of your sql files are listed in otuput.txt (with full path?)

Comment: Nope, only writes `Willem started the batch process at 11:18:51.16`

Comment: It seems your for- command didn't work. See this [page](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) to fix this problem. After that we could go one with the sql-scripts

Answer (score 9):

You've got an unmatched parenthesis, there.
Try

for %%f in (*.sql) do sqlcmd.exe  -S servername -E   -d databasename -i %%f >>output.txt

I just saved it in a .cmd file and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. You can do it with :r command of `SQLCMD`.

I strongly recommend you to read this article and do it with `SQLCMD`

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1543/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-multiple-sql-server-scripts/

Comment: Is this possible to run all script in transaction? and if any error in any script then rollback and stop execution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open source utility with source code http://scriptzrunner.codeplex.com/

This utility was written in c# and allows you to drag and drop many sql files and start running them against a database.

Answer (score 0):

Some batch trick

```
cd %~dp0 //use this if you use 'for xxx in', it solved most of my problems 

ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt


for %%f in (*.sql) do (
(
sqlcmd.exe  -S servername -E -d databasename -i %%f >>output.txt
)
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Batch Compiler](http://holdlock.com) add-in for SMSS, it let's you run multiple scripts at once, create SQLCMD scripts or consolidate them into a *.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Oracle SQL files through a Batch program, then the code below will be useful. Just copy & change the Database credential and DB names

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("%~dp0"*.sql) do echo @"%%~fi" >> "%~dp0all.sql"

echo exit | sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @"c:\users\all.sql"
pause
```

Basically, you need to put this batch file in the folder where you have all the SQL files. It will first get all the sql file names in the directory and load their full path with the sql file names. Then, it will write into a file `all.sql` and then sqlplus will call that `all.sql` to execute all the sql files that you have in that directory.